# Change what app the command "Open ." opens

Tags: terminal, finder, applications

How can you open another file manager with the command `Open .`? I've tried the command, and it opens Finder. I'd like it to open another file manager, if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
open . -a "App name"
```